# Trying to use a debugger in rails 3 - ruby 1.9.3 [Refactoring]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I'm trying to use a debugger in a homework assignment I'm working on. I installed the gem ruby-debug19, but I can't put it to use. Whenever I put the statement ruby-debug in a method, and I go to the console server it doesn't respond. It's like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob72R.jpg

```
  def index
    ruby-debug
    @search = params[:search] ? params[:search] : {}

    @articles = Article.search_with_pagination(@search, {:page => params[:page], :per_page => this_blog.admin_display_elements})

    if request.xhr?
      render :partial => 'article_list', :locals => { :articles => @articles }
    else
      @article = Article.new(params[:article])
    end
  end
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to add code snippets of how you are using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something flexible with the option of setting breakpoints and navigating through code I can recommend [`pry-debugger`](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger). If you want something with glitter and magic [`jazz_hands`](https://github.com/nixme/jazz_hands) is the gem you are looking for.

Comment: I'm using pry-debugger. Thanks !

Comment: @FranGoitia glad that I could help!